Create Excel ranges from list of cell addresses with OfficeJs
I am working with an Excel add-in and am given a list of cell addresses that contain custom functions that I need to reference, ie.,
 ["A1","B1","C1","F2","F3","F4","G2","G3","G4","X5"] 

This list of cell addresses can vary from one cell address to a list of many and can vary from a row to a column to every other cell, it's all up to the user for where they place their custom function.
I need to create a list of ranges the same way Excel creates them to display to the user.
So for the example array I would expect my return to be
["A1:C1","F2:G4","X5:X5"].
This would look something like


const exampleCells1 = ["A1","B1","C1","F3","F4","G3","G4","X1"];
const exampleCells2 = ["AN299","AN300"];
const exampleCells3 = ["P44"];

const getRanges = (cells) => {
  const ranges = [];
  // createRanges
  return ranges;
 };
 
 
 //expected returns being
 // getRanges(exampleCells1) => ["A1:C1","F3:G4","X1:X1"];
 // getRanges(exampleCells2) => ["AN299:AN300"];
 // getRanges(exampleCells3) => ["P44:P44"];




Please provide more details on the issue including an [mcve].

are the ranges clearly separated or do you have sometimes close ranges with different areas? what have you tried?

What is the context for this list of cell addresses?

How do you know if a1 a2 b1 b2 is one range or two ranges next to each other (or 3 or 4 ranges), or does it not matter?

Okay so I have no idea about Excel nor OfficeJS, but here's a possible solution using plain JavaScript.
The only assumption I've made is that cells in a same range are ordered (otherwise, the problem would be unsolvable) - either by row or by column.


const cells = ["A1","B1","C1","F2","F3","F4","G2","G3","G4","X5"];

function rangesFromCells(cells) {
  /* 'range' is a temp array containing the
  range currently being explored. */
  let range = [];
  /* 'dir' contains the direction of the
  current range's exploration. */
  let dir = 0;
  /* 'sizeRange' contains the size of 'range' in the
  direction of exploration: if it's being explored by row,
  its number of columns; otherwise, its number of rows.
  'currentSize' - the same thing, but for the current
  row/column inside the current range. */
  let [sizeRange, currentSize] = [null, 0];
  const output = cells.reduce(function (acc, cell) {
    switch (range.length) {
        case 0:
        range.push(cell);
        return acc;
      case 1:
        dir = whichDirection(range.at(-1), cell);
        if (!dir) {
            acc.push(range[0].concat(':', range[0]));
            range = [cell];
          return acc;
        } else {
            range.push(cell);
          currentSize = 2;
          return acc;
        }
      default:
        switch (whichDirection(range.at(-1), cell)) {
            case dir:  // The direction stays the same.
            /* 'sizeRange' is null if 'range' contains only one row/column. */
            if (!sizeRange || currentSize < sizeRange) {
              range.push(cell);
              currentSize++;
              return acc;
            } else {  /* If a cell is added that exceeds the size
            of the current range, start a new range with said cell. */
              acc.push(range[0].concat(':', range.at(-1)));
              range = [cell];
              [sizeRange, currentSize] = [null, 0];
              return acc;
            }
          case 0:
            sizeRange ??= range.length;
            /* If the latest cell is adjacent to the first cell in the current
            row/column, with an opposite direction of 'dir', it can mean the
            beginning of a new row/column inside the same range. */
            if (dir + whichDirection(range.at(-sizeRange), cell) === 0) {
                currentSize = 1;
              range.push(cell);
              return acc;
            }   /* Otherwise, a new, different range begins, so fall-through. */
          /* If the direction changes from 'down' to 'right' or
          viceversa, necessarily a new different range is starting. */
          default:
            /* If 'range' is a rectangle, it represents one range. */
            if (currentSize === sizeRange) {
              acc.push(range[0].concat(':', range.at(-1)));
              range = [cell];
              [sizeRange, currentSize] = [null, 0];
              return acc;
            /* Otherwise, the last row/column constitutes a separate range. */
            } else {
                acc.push(range[0].concat(':', range.at(-currentSize-1)));
              acc.push(range.at(-currentSize).concat(':', range.at(-1)));
              range = [cell];
              [sizeRange, currentSize] = [null, 0];
              return acc;
            }
        }
    }
  }, []);
  /* When 'reduce' has processed the last item in 'cells',
  the last range is still contained in 'range'. */
  if (!sizeRange || currentSize === sizeRange) {
    output.push(range[0].concat(':', range.at(-1)));
  } else {
    output.push(range[0].concat(':', range.at(-currentSize-1)));
    output.push(range.at(-currentSize).concat(':', range.at(-1)));
  }
  return output;
}

/**
 * Returns whether a cell is immediately to the right \
 * or immediately down of another cell.
 *
 * @param {string} cell1 - The A1 notation of the first cell.
 * @param {string} cell2 - The A1 notation of the second cell.
 * @return {number} 1 if the second cell is to the right \
 * of the first one; -1, if it's down; 0 otherwise.
 */
function whichDirection(cell1, cell2) {
  const [row1, row2] = cell1.concat(cell2).match(/(?:[0-9]+)/g).map(Number);
    const [col1, col2] = cell1.concat(cell2).match(/(?:[A-Z]+)/g);
  switch (true) {
    case col1 === col2 && row2 === row1+1:
        return -1;
    case row1 === row2 && col2 === nextCol(col1):
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
  }
}

/**
 * Returns the letters of a given column's right neighbour.
 *
 * @param {string} col - The name of the column.
 * @return {string} The name of the next column.
 */
function nextCol(col) {
    switch (col.at(-1)) {
    case undefined:
        return 'A';
    case 'Z':
        return nextCol(col.slice(0, -1)).concat('A');
    default:
        return col.slice(0, -1).concat(String.fromCharCode(col.charCodeAt(col.length-1) + 1));
  }
}

console.log(rangesFromCells(cells));



